# clarification of what does it mean a Hilbert lattice?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was searching to find and understand the meaning of a Hilbert Lattice. I could not find on Google something simply define what is a Hilbert lattice. Can any one help me and explain to me what is a Hilbert lattice? if possible an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at Schaefer's book „[Banach Lattices And Positive Operators](http://books.google.de/books/about/Banach_lattices_and_positive_operators.html?id=GQ-oAAAAIAAJ)“. In Definition 6.6 of this book the term „Hilbert lattice“ is defined:

> By a *Hilbert lattice* we understand a Banach lattice whose underlying Banach space is a Hilbert space.

I cite Definition 5.1 from Schaefer's book:

> Let $E$ be a vector lattice. A semi-norm (norm) $p$ on $E$ is called a *lattice semi-norm* (*lattice norm*) if $\lvert x \rvert \leq \lvert y \rvert$ implies $p(x) \leq p(y)$ for all $x,y \in E$. If $p$ is a lattice norm on $E$, the pair $(E,p)$ is a called a *normed (vector) lattice*; if, in addition, $(E,p)$ is norm complete it is called a *Banach lattice*.

Comment: Great. What is a Banach lattice?